# Why can't quantum phase noise in radio astronomy amplifiers just be filtered out after down conversion, instead of down-converting first?

Tags: noise, phase, linear-phase, conversion

In the related Astronomy SE questions below and their answers, it has become apparent that radio telescope arrays down convert their highest frequency bands before the first stage of amplification.

- [Do circa 1 THz radio telescope front end amplifiers actually down convert before amplifying? At what frequency does amplification become untenable?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/48829/7982)
- [Highest frequency that's been imaged by a radio telescope?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35975/7982)

In the online course at nrao.edu [Essential Radio Astronomy](https://science.nrao.edu/opportunities/courses/era/) the [Introduction](https://www.cv.nrao.edu/%7Esransom/web/Ch1.html) argues that 1 THz is the absolute upper boundary to far infrared in astronomy (there's semantic overlap between millimeter waves and far infrared that context).

In Yuh-Jing Hwang's *2018 ASIAA Summer Student Lecture Series 1* slides [Engineering Aspects for Radio Astronomy](https://events.asiaa.sinica.edu.tw/ssp/viewFile.php?i=e0ac09c7b674289316abbcb7ed062f65&t=L) the crossover between amplify-first and down convert-first is circa 100 GHz, as shown in the two screenshots below, and that *might* correspond to the following, from [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/48829/7982):

> **Just for example** [ALMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atacama_Large_Millimeter_Array) has ten different frequency bands listed at ESO's [ALMA Receiver Bands](https://www.eso.org/public/teles-instr/alma/receiver-bands/).
>
> The table says that the lowest two bands (35–50 and 65–90 GHz) use [High-electron-mobility transistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-electron-mobility_transistor) receiver technology, while the top eight use "SIS".

Note that according to the linked presentation's slide #33-35 SIS (also ) is a barrier Superconducting-Insulator-Superconductor barrier tunneling detector.

**Question:** Why can't quantum phase noise in radio astronomy amplifiers just be filtered out after down conversion, instead of down-converting first?

I'm wondering what it is about quantum phase noise induced by the amplifier that allows it to survive down-conversion to a much lower frequency. The spatial resolution of the interferometer will be linked to the primary submillimeter wavelength (~1 THz), not the 2 GHz baseband after down-conversion. A 1 radian $\Delta \phi$ radian at 1 THz would correspond to 2 milli-radians at 2 GHz, and yet this is more easily achieved.

The reason phase noise is so critical is that these receivers are used in large arrays of dish antennas for interferometric imaging. Also note that the signal is then digitized with a very few bit ADC, then transmitted digitally to a central computer called a correlator where interferometry takes place computationally in real time.

Also related in Astronomy SE:

- [How does ALMA produce stable, mutually coherent ~THz local oscillators for all of their dishes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28666/7982)
- [How does the Event Horizon Telescope implement the interferometry?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/20082/7982)
- [How, precisely, do radio astronomers detect (and record) the phases of waves for interferometry?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/46655/7982)
- [Is there any work underway to push the long baseline capabilities of the Event Horizon Telescope to sub-millimeter wavelengths?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35757/7982)

---

From the linked presentation:

> Heterodyne receiver:
>
> – for low frequency, the signal is amplified and then divided into different frequency bands and then digitized, correlated and generated the digital spectral information.
>
> – For millimeter-wave frequency, the signal is amplified and then down-convert the frequency (by mixer) into intermediate frequency (IF), amplified and then divided into different frequency bands and then digitized, correlated and generated the digital spectral information.
>
> – **For submillimeter-wave frequency, no low-noise amplifier with quantum-limited performance available, signal is down-convert the frequency (by mixer) into intermediate frequency (IF), amplified and then** divided into different frequency bands and then digitized, correlated and generated the digital spectral information.
>
> #### Suitable for f<sub>RF</sub> < 116 GHz
>
> - Receiver Feed
> - RF Amplifier
> - Mixer and Local Oscillator
> - IF Amplifier
> - IF Low-pass filter
> - Spectrometer or Correlator
>
> #### Suitable for f<sub>RF</sub> > 84GHz
>
> - Receiver Feed
> - RF Amplifier (omitted)
> - Mixer and Local Oscillator
> - IF Amplifier
> - IF Low-pass filter
> - Spectrometer or Correlator

click for full size:

[image: screenshot from Yuh-Jing Hwang's '2018 ASIAA Summer Student Lecture Series 1' slides "Engineering Aspects for Radio Astronomy" https://events.asiaa.sinica.edu.tw/ssp/viewFile.php?i=e0ac09c7b674289316abbcb7ed062f65&t=L] [image: screenshot from Yuh-Jing Hwang's '2018 ASIAA Summer Student Lecture Series 1' slides "Engineering Aspects for Radio Astronomy" https://events.asiaa.sinica.edu.tw/ssp/viewFile.php?i=e0ac09c7b674289316abbcb7ed062f65&t=L]

Comment: Note that I don't argue that one would want to down-convert first, but only ask why this would not work.

Comment: "Why can't quantum phase noise in radio astronomy amplifiers just be filtered out after down conversion, instead of down-converting first?"  This seems to be circular.  Doesn't down-converting first _imply_ filtering after down conversion?

Comment: @TimWescott No, it *does not* imply filtering of phase noise. There is of course frequency selection via filtering, but that's not what I've asked about.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty smart and it sure reads that way to me.  Maybe you should figure out how to reword it for clarity and edit your question.

Comment: @TimWescott then delete your preemptive comment-as-answer so that it does not conflict with it, otherwise I can't, especially now that you understand the difference between filtering to remove phase noise and filtering as part of frequency down-conversion.

Comment: @uhoh please clarify what you mean by filtering of phase noise if you are not doing it with frequency selective filtering

Comment: @DanBoschen if such a filter doesn't exist that might be an answer to the question as-asked. If I could come up with such a filter and describe it, then I'd already have the answer to my question. I could split this up into two questions I suppose, but I usually refrain from substantial edits once answers [correct or not](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82041/why-cant-quantum-phase-noise-in-radio-astronomy-amplifiers-just-be-filtered-out?noredirect=1#comment172205_82043) are posted.

Comment: Yes I agree, don't change your question as it is now aligned with the answer given. I had assumed you had a "phase filtering" technique in mind that wasn't in fact a frequency selective filter, or assumed they would be different filters. That may in fact lead to another and more concise question from you-- I welcome that vs ongoing discussion in the comments.

Comment: @DanBoschen it was a [gedankenfilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment) Per the last few comments under TimWescott's answer I might adjust it to the extent that it further aligns with their answer pending their okay and no other answers, and ask something about my hypothetical "phase noise filter" separately (or not).

Comment: Do you already have a good understanding of phase noise in a communication system and the related considerations for receivers? If not, that may be the good place to start-- there are some existing links here already I can point you to to start with that may fill in some of the gaps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134903/discussion-between-dan-boschen-and-uhoh).

Comment: @DanBoschen I just now saw your helpful information in chat, either I didn't get a notification or somehow missed it (I get a lot of notifications per day). I'll dig in and see how deep I can get. *Thanks!* I'm commenting here because the room is currently locked.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering what it is about quantum phase noise induced by the amplifier that allows it to survive down-conversion to a much lower frequency.

In general, the down-conversion process conserves phase shifts, not timing shifts.  The basic heterodyne equation is just trigonometry (assuming $\omega_2> \omega_1$ and after the low pass filter):
$$\cos \omega_1 t \cdot \cos (\omega_2 t + \phi) = 
    \frac{1}{2} \cos \left((\omega_2 - \omega_1)t + \phi \right ) \tag 1$$

So a timing error at $1\mathrm{THz}$ that leads to a 1 milliradian phase shift will result in a 1 milliradian phase shift once the signal is converted down to $100 \mathrm{GHz}$.

Comment: You posted an answer before seeing [my reply to your comment](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82041/why-cant-quantum-phase-noise-in-radio-astronomy-amplifiers-just-be-filtered-out?noredirect=1#comment172195_82041)

Comment: ...and your equation is both unsourced and at first glance possibly incorrect. I tried $\omega_1, \omega_2 = 10, 1$ and $t, \phi = 4.2, e$. The left side is -0.322 and the right is 0.203 and 0.500 Adding back the missing $t$ doesn't seem to help the equality. I understand "[Well, I'm pretty smart](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82041/why-cant-quantum-phase-noise-in-radio-astronomy-amplifiers-just-be-filtered-out?noredirect=1#comment172196_82041)" but I think this answer attempts to oversimplify the problem.

Comment: I believe Tim's equation is now correct, not just due to him being pretty smart (which he really is!) but also simple trigonometry and understanding the down-conversion process is a product of the LO  at freq $\omega_1$ with the received signal at freq $\omega_2$ .  If you need a source: http://www.sosmath.com/trig/prodform/prodform.html Importantly, the main point of his answer is correct and gets to the root of your question (I believe).

Comment: @uhoh Note that $$\cos \omega_1 t \cdot \cos (\omega_2 t + \phi) = 
    \frac{1}{2} (\cos \left((\omega_2 - \omega_1)t + \phi \right ) +  \cos \left((\omega_2 + \omega_1)t + \phi \right ))$$
After applying the lowpass filter we have $$\frac{1}{2} (\cos \left((\omega_2 - \omega_1)t + \phi \right )$$

Comment: @S.H.W Okay! Yes that now works. I think the original equation and its edit were simply shorthand, i.e. "you know what I mean" notation.

Comment: @DanBoschen thanks for your input, and with a further edit it seems to be a nicely wrapped up answer for me. With (at)TImWescott's permission I will adjust the question's wording to match this answer, then see if I have a further question.

Comment: Yes, I think he hit it spot on for you in that you first thought the phase would be changed leading to your curiousity- if that is indeed the case, please remember to select as the "right answer" and thanks for the good questions.

Comment: @DanBoschen there's still nothing here about quantum phase noise and why it's reduced by down-conversion before amplification. I'm guessing that for a given amplifier it's worse at high frequency to due to some fundamental principle. If so, and given the results in S.H.W's comment, that would explain why it can be reduced by down-conversion before amplification. With (at)TimWescott's permission I'll alter the question to remove mention of filtering, and think about if there's a separate question in it or not Just fyi I usually take about a week to let questions "ripen" before I accept anything

Comment: @TimWescott okay with you if I remove the "filtering" aspect of the question as discussed in comments above?

Comment: Tim's point is the phase noise is NOT reduced but remains the same. In your question I got the understanding that you thought the opposite because of this statement: "A 1 radian Δϕ radian at 1 THz would correspond to 2 milli-radians at 2 GHz". This is why I  thought he cleared it up for you.

Comment: I'm not touching the "quantum phase noise" because this is a *DSP* group, and "quantum" is about physics.  So if the "quantum" part is retained, through demodulation, somehow (i.e., if quantum states stay entangled, and how you demodulate it either retains the entanglement or destroys it), then _that's physics_, not signal processing.

Comment: @TimWescott I just saw your comment; didn't receive a notification. Since I asked about quantum phase noise and you're not touching it can we at least say if it's known that signal processing in all its forms can not address quantum noise, or if it's just your particular answer that's avoiding it?

Comment: @TimWescott fyi asked in meta: [How to handle mismatch between a quantum phase noise question and the current answer? "...because this is a DSP group, and 'quantum' is about physics"](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/25659)